# .hover Jquery Blinks on Mouseover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a `div` when someone mouseover the image.

**Here is my jQuery code:**

```
var $i = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$i("#overlay-<?php echo $j;?>").hover(function () {
    $i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>").fadeIn("fast");
    $i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>").fadeOut("fast");   
});
```

**Here is My HTML Code**

```
<div id="overlay-show-1" class="overlay-show" style="display: block;">
 <div class="product-price">
 <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Marotte Top"href="http://sabbathshop.com/index.php/apparel/marotte-top.html">Marotte Top</a></h2>   
 <div class="price-box">
 <span id="product-price-180" class="regular-price">
  <span class="price">$80.00</span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="price-bottombg"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have edited the above code. Now, the div that I want to show keeps blinking repeatedly without any pause. How can I control it so that it fades out only when my customer removes the mouse over the "#overlay-<?php echo $j;?>"

Answer (score 0):

`$i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>").is(":hidden")` will return an object whether or not there are matching selectors.

You should check the `length` to see if there are matches:

```
if ($i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>").is(":hidden").length>0) {
```

---

In response to your update:

As you only have one function parameter for the `.hover()` event, this will be actioned when you hover over **and** when you hover out.

Also in your function you are calling `fadeIn` followed directly by `fadeOut`. Therefore this is going to cause the element to fade in, and then immediately fade out again (causing the flicker which you mentioned).

You should change your code to only `fadeIn` on hover over, and only `fadeOut` on hover out.

```
$i("#overlay-<?php echo $j;?>").hover(function () {
    $i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>").fadeIn("fast"); 
}, function(){
    $i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>").fadeOut("fast");  
});
```

Comment: I tried this but still it doesn't work. Now the hover doesn;t work anymore.

Comment: @Muhammad Source code in the browser will be rendered HTML. Therefore no PHP

Comment: The code which you have edited doesn't seem correct. I need the fade in and out to work on #overlay-show-<?php echo $j;?>. You mentioned it on #overlay-<?php echo $j;?> which seems to fadeout the complete div

Comment: Ahh I didnt realise the selectors were different. I've updated my answer

Comment: the flicker is back again. I used your new code but the flicker is back again.

Comment: can you please look into this flicker problem?